# how to break multiple Ajax promise chain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, promise

I have multiple ajax request working together, and each request based on previous request's result, if the previous request return false, the chain should stops.

Here's some code

```
 //here is a promise chain    

 return this.getBand(id)
            .then(this.getAlbum)
            .then(this.getSong);
//ajax request for getBand
function getBand(id) {
  return Ember.$.ajax({
    data:{id: id},
    url: urls.bandUrl,
  }).then(function(result){
    return result;
  });
};

//ajax request for getAlbum
function getAlbum(result){
  if(result.pass) {
  var bandName = result.name;
  return Ember.$.ajax({
   //...
  })
  } else {
  // i wanna stop the promise chain here, how to do that?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can indicate an error in the chain by returning a [rejected Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.reject/):

```
function getAlbum(result) {
  if (result.pass) {
    // ...
  } else {
    return Ember.$.Deferred().reject('Previous result did not pass');
  }
}
```

You can also revise `getBand()` to check `result.pass` itself, so `getAlbum()` won't be invoked unless it did pass.

```
function getBand(id) {
  return Ember.$.ajax({
    // ...
  }).then(function(result){
    return result.pass ?
      result :
      Ember.$.Deferred().reject('Band could not be found (' + id + ').');
  });
};
```

The chain won't completely stop, but it will only proceed to `fail` callbacks/filters, provided to [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) as a 2nd argument or [`.fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/).

```
return this.getBand(id)
    .then(this.getAlbum)
    .then(this.getSong)
    .fail(function (error) {
        // show `error` to user
    });
```

Comment: Doing ` Ember.$.Deferred().reject(...)` is pretty silly, it's much better to make the ajax request using ember itself using RSVP promises which'd let you `throw`.